# ionic3 - Copy a newly created custom folder from inside src to www

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, gulp

In Ionic3 project inside 'src' i have created a folder named 'Raja'.

It have few of js library files. When give ionic serve or taking build i need to copy/bring folder 'Raja' from 'src' folder to 'www' folder.

Example how assets folder is getting copy from 'src' to 'www' in run time. I need to do the same. How the assets configuration working. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you put that folder inside of the `assets` folder? That way it will be automatically copied to the `www` folder during Ionic build

Comment: It's already developed project , I'm migrating to ionic 2 to ionic 3 . Lots of changes need to do in case of moving inside assets

Answer (score 0):

You can override copy config of Ionic 3.

You can follow here: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts#overriding-config-files

And default copy config here: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/blob/master/config/copy.config.js